# Nova 2.1 stop command (graphical user interface for electrochemical measurement)

Tags: electrochemistry, polymers

We are doing an electrochemical polymerization of a semiconducting polymer and would like to try it as a pulsed square wave with defined frequency (i.e. 100 Hz) and duty cycle (i.e. 50%), but fixing a control over the total deposited charge (stopping the deposition at a target charge value, i.e. 100 μC). How can I do to set the stop command?

I manage to do it easily with the "record signal" block in a fixed voltage electropolimerization (using the "Apply" block to set a voltage potential), where the block can also integrate the current value and measure the charge in real-time.

However, with the "chrono methods" block for the square wave development, it is not easy to link a "record signal" block to the "chrono methods" block. They seems always to be connected in series, occurring one after another. Thus, the deposition always stops at the end of the total selected cycles, overcoming the charge threshold I selected.

Using the "repeat measurement" block, I have seen that there are time-intervals between the calling of the "apply" block, thus the duty cycle changes and the measurement is slower than the selected frequency.
Do you have any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Can you please edit to say what ‘Nova’ is and what the ‘blocks’ are? I would guess you have some electrochemical instrument that has a graphical user interface (GUI) software system, but it would be best to just give a bit more information.

Comment: Check [this instruction manual](https://www.metrohm-autolab.com/download/NovaSoftware/User_manual_1.10.pdf) maybe?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, it's Nova 2.1 and the blocks are block diagram for programming the measurements, similar to the LabView software system.